# Python Interpreter/IDE for android?

Tags: android, python, ide

I'm looking for an Android app that supports Python 3.7 +

Tried to install python through [Termus](https://termux.com/)

`apt install python` got error as inaccessible or not found.

Tried [Python Interpreter on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793158/python-interpreter-on-android) multiple apps but nothing helped. Expect [Pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=en), but it is a paid app.

Would like to know more apps free/paid which can really work fine with multiple Python libraries of Machine Learning & Statistical Analysis

Answer (score 3):

[Pydroid3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.iiec.pydroid3&hl=en) is available as both Free and Paid editions and I don't think that the price for it is too exorbitant for most people.

On the **Paid** edition going to the pip window and selecting Quick Install produces a screen like:
[image: Pydroid3 pip quick install page]